# Do I need ReportViewer installed on web server?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, reporting-services, reportviewer

If I have the assemblies (Common.dll & WebForms.dll) in the bin folder of my web application, do I need to have Microsoft ReportViewer Redistributable installed on my web server?

Answer (score 3):

No, but I found I required these .ddl's in my bin for it to work.

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll

If you could give more details as well, which version of SSRS and local or remote mode. The above are for the latest version SSRS 2010 ReportViewer and in local mode.